# What is the structure of the sentence "For Bill to have been arrested so soon was disappointing." according to the GB theory

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, generative-grammar

Please consider the following:

(0) For Bill to have been arrested so soon was disappointing.

(1) ?It was disappointing for Bill to have been arrested so soon.

If the sentence (1) is grammatical, it seems to suggest, that disappointing is an adjective which has one theta-role available. Compare:

(2) That Bill has been arrested so soon disappointed Mary.

(3) That Bill has been arrested so soon was disappointing (for Mary).

See also:

(4) It was disappointing that Bill was arrested so soon.

(5) That Bill was arrested so soon was disappointing.

One analysis might posit two traces in the sentence (0):

[CP For Bill1 to have been arrested t1 so soon]2 was disappointing t2.

So the D-structure is:

e2 was disappointing [CP for e1 to have been arrested Bill so soon].

It makes the analysis of sentence (1) obvious. 
If the analysis is incorrect, how could you explain (1)?

Another analysis might be (D-structure):

[CP for e1 to have been arrested Bill so soon] is disappointing.

In this case the CP has to move to a position after disappointing:

e2 is disappointing [CP for e1 to have been arrested Bill so soon].

But what position could it move into? In addition it should leave a trace, not "it".

Which of those two analyses is correct (if any)? If the first one is correct it seems like "is disappointing" works like an unaccusative/passive verb. How to analyze it? "disappointing" is an adjective, but what is the copula? (I or V?)

Some analyzes are:

[I' [I -s] [VP [V' [V be] [AP [A' [A disappointing] [CP trace] ] ] ] ] ]

"-s" is an auxiliary
"be" is a verb

[I' [I is] [AP [A' [A disappointing] [CP trace] ] ] ]

"is" is an auxiliary

What is the correct analysis according to GB?

Comment: What made you mark (1) with a question mark?  Are you indicating that the sentence is questionable?  (I don't see anything wrong with it.)  Or are you indicating your own uncertainty?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, and I was not sure about the grammaticality, that's why I marked it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is derived from

> [s
>       [np
>        [s
>            [np `Unspec` np]
>              [vp *arrested* [np *Bill* np] [advp *so soon*] vp]
>           s]
>        np]
>      [vp *was disappointing* vp]
>     s]

The subject complement clause

- [s [np `Unspec` np] [vp *arrested* [np *Bill* np] [advp *so soon*] vp] s]

is passivized, producing

- [s [np *Bill* np] [vp *was arrested so soon* vp] s]

This is marked with a *`for-to`* infinitive complementizer required by the matrix predicate *disappointing*.

- [s *`For`* [np *Bill* np] *`to`* [vp *have been arrested so soon* vp] s]

producing the infinitive complement clause subject of the psych predicate adjective *(be) disappointing*.
(The *have* comes from converting the past tense morpheme in *was arrested* into an infinitive).

The **next** step, which is **not** taken in the example, is to Extrapose the heavy subject, producing

- ***It*** was disappointing for Bill to have been arrested so soon.

which is a much easier structure to parse, since it's completely right-branching.

This is just a sketch, of course. What counts as "the structure of" this sentence, in your case, is a matter to be negoiated with your teacher, or confessor, or whoever determines `The Rules`.

Comment: Your answer is presupposing the existence of a finite VP constituent? How does your system motivate the existence of that constituent?

Comment: At one stage of the derivation, sure. See McCawley 1998 Ch. 3, on tests for constituency. For a more specific version, see [the VP guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) (which starts where the [logic guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) leaves off).

Comment: I do not have access to McCawley at present. The VP guide you provide seems to jump to the conclusion that the subject is a dependent of S without justification (by way of Subject Formation). Constituency tests provide little evidence for the existence of a finite VP constituent. Would you like me to demonstrate this fact?

Comment: A `VP` is simply an `S` that has lost its subject. There are all kinds of ways that can happen, but the constituents are clearly `S`, `NP`, and `VP`. Unless you want to call "VP" `V'`, which I don't, since it introduces unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Whether you call it finite VP or V' is not important. Either way, I'm asking for emperical evidence motivating the presupposition that the binary S --> NP VP division exists. It is a basic question that most phrase structure grammars never attempt to answer. Constituency tests suggest that the division does not exist.

Comment: For instance, permutation tests such as topicalization do not support its existence, e.g. That is disappointing --> *Is disappoiting that. Clefting does not support its existence, e.g. *It is is disappointing that that. Pseudoclefting does not support its existence, e.g. *What it is is is disappointing. Answer fragments do not support its existence, e.g. What is it? --*Is disappointing. Proform substitution does not support its existence, e.g. *It does so (does so = is disappointing).

Comment: @jlawler Thank you for the answer. What kind of movement is this heavy subject movement? What position the heavy subject ends in? It does not move to a case marked position, so I assume it is an example of wh-movement? Or maybe it is something else. And besides that, why it does not leave a trace, but "it" instead? Can you suggest some articles concerning this kind of movement? Thank you!

Comment: I have found that the process you've described is called it-extraposition. Do you know any articles which describe it in the GB framework. Besides that, I have noticed another issue. Compare the following sentence: His performance was disappointing. In this sentence the NP "his performance" is theta-marked. But in the sentence (1) "it" is in a theta marked position. But "it" cannot be theta-marked afaik. How is it possible to theta-mark "for Bill..." if it is not in an A-position? Does "it" form a chain with the CP?

Comment: No, @unoduetre, I don't know what they call it in the GB framework, or in any other MITish theory; I swore off them in 1971 and I've been clean ever since. If you want to see more about Extraposition, [try this link](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+Extraposition). And, Tim, sorry, but I'm not going to retype McCawley for you, nor argue in comments. Consult your library, or get your own copy if you're doing serious syntactic research.